# Javascript window.location within php returned by json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

i'm trying to put a js window.location within my json output to update a DIV with that javascript code to redirect the user. Only problem here is that my script just doesn't do anything anymore after trying to put the javascript within the json output.

```
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<h3>Deel 1 is afgerond, <a href='/shop/?,69'>KLIK HIER</a> om door te gaan naar de begin pagina.</h3>";
$result["html"] .= "<script type="text/javascript"><!-- function Redirect() { window.location="http://www.newlocation.com"; } setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000); //--></script>";

} else {
$result["error"] = true;
$result["html"] = "<h3>Error; Neem contact op met de webmaster</h3>";
}
```

Now the script dies without doing anything because of this JS.

i just don't know howto format it. I tried changing the " to ' and putting \ before the " but none of it works. anybody ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$result = array("error" => false, "html" => null);
$result["error"] = false;
$result["html"] = "<h3>Deel 1 is afgerond, <a href='/shop/?,69'>KLIK HIER</a> om door te gaan naar de begin pagina.</h3>";
$result["html"] .= "<script type='text/javascript'>setTimeout(function () { window.location='http://www.newlocation.com'; }, 10000);</script>";
```

Changes:

- cleaned up apostrophes/quotes
- removed unnecessary comment tags
- changed setTimeout to invoke the function directly rather than via name, which is simpler

Comment: Thanks! Gonna use that js change as well !

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some issues with this line:

`$result["html"] .= "<script type="text/javascript"><!-- function Redirect() { window.location="http://www.newlocation.com"; } setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000); //--></script>";`

Change it to:

`$result["html"] .= "<script type='text/javascript'> function Redirect() { window.location='http://www.newlocation.com'; } setTimeout('Redirect()', 10000); </script>";`

Comment: Looks like i forgot the change the "" in the <script> tags as well as removing the comment marks.. i must be to high or something. Thanks men!